# Find the sum of three-digit numbers, that are co-prime with 10.

Tags: combinatorics

Find the sum of three-digit numbers, that are co-prime with 10. After an hour of desperate thinking, I have proved the formula to calculate the sum of the numbers co-prime with N and less than N. And now I need to find the sum of all **three-digit numbers** that are co-prime with 10. I want to know, can I change and use that formula for calculation, or is there another way to do this? Help me, please.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  How about adding all the three-digit numbers, subtracting the sum of those that are multiples of $2$ and the sum of those that are multiples of $5$, and adding back in the sum of those that are multiples of $10$ (since they were subtracted twice, once as multiples of $2$ and once as multiples of $5$)?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll try it!

Comment: Note that being coprime with $10$ is equivalent to the last digit being $1$, $3$, $7$ or $9$.